# How to encode string that give different encode character for same original string character?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, encode

We have e-commerce site in which have one item (mobile) with two types of category. One is `'good-mobiles'` and other is `'bad-mobiles'`.

We decide this by running some calculation on some parameter.

We have two database tables one store all good-mobiles (table name: `gMobiles`) and other store all bad-mobiles (table name: `bMobiles`). We add 'g' or 'b' before with some auto-incremented id and store it in respective tables.

So `gMobiles` contains all id which start with 'g' and bMobiles contains all id which start with 'b'. And we add this ids into url of details page.

**Now problem is user can easily identify whether mobile is bad or good just by looking at urls or hovering on items on listing page in desktop.**

To solve this problem we thought of using encoding (for example base64 encoding), but the problem with encoding is that in encoded string 'g' is replaced by some other characters and for all 'g' it always give same characters, so it will not solve our problem.

```
Orig Text | Encoded Text
----------|-------------
    g1234 | ZDEyMz
    g1267 | ZDEyUS
    b3456 | YTEyMz
    b7654 | YTMyQs
    g7654 | ZDMyQs
```

We are not using encryption because encrypted string will be long (for 8 character input string it will give 40-50 character).

Is there any way which will give result string to be sort and one cannot able to find out whether mobile is good or bad just by looking at URLs.

Comment: Why not using a GUID for every product?

Comment: Please don't use code font for non-code items. It makes your post *really* hard to read.

Comment: Have you thought of using POST instead of GET so typical user won't see it as easily ?

Comment: Next, if this information is meant to be hidden from users (which you should really consider to start with) why does it need to be present in the ID at all? Why not have a separate table which lets you tell which is which? Aside from anything else, that would allow you to change which category an item falls into later, without changing the ID.

Comment: Looks at all the html characters (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references), and/or use different encoding like windows 1252 encoding.

Comment: @jdweng: No, using different encodings here is a really, really bad idea IMO.

Comment: What about different colors?

Comment: I would argue that it's a poor design choice to have separate tables for good mobiles and bad mobiles in the first place, assuming that the only thing that's separating the good from the bad is that one property I would suggest using a single table and just add a column to indicate if the mobile is good or bad. That way, you don't have to expose that information to the user at all and you have a better database design.

Comment: @NicoRiff select query on 32 character will impact performance(and also query will be slow)

Comment: _"select query on 32 character will impact performance"_ - I highly doubt this will be anywhere near noticeable.

Comment: @yajiv You are wrong. If using GUID "slows" your query, then you have a seriuos design and implementation problem

Comment: I read that when we have large data(more than 1M) it will impact performance.

Comment: @NicoRiff Actually guid is rarely a good choice for a primary key - it's going to create a very highly fragmented index and that does have it's costs.

Comment: @JonSkeet "Why not have a separate table which lets you tell which is which? " how can I achieve this. In separete table I have mapped something(let say x ) against my current id. I want to know how can I achieve this x(which is unique).

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking. You either have a new table with two columns, "ItemId" and "IsGood", or you just make that an extra column of an existing table. If you're actually asking how to generate unique IDs, that's an entirely different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet you are suggesting merging two tables as suggested in answer. I want to know whether it is possible to stop user from knowing category without changing our current two table design.(using some encoding like youtube or some encryption which give short output)

Comment: Possible? Almost certainly. Assuming you control ID generation, you could hash the ID with a secret salt and just look at the last bit of the hash, discarding the ID if it isn't doesn't work out the way you want. That's a really, really bad idea though. You shouldn't be trying to embed extra information in the ID.

Comment: @JonSkeet _"look at the last bit of the hash, discarding the ID if it isn't doesn't work out the way you want"_ didn't get this.

Comment: If you want to generate an ID for a "good" mobile, and "good" IDs have a hash that ends in a 1, then just keep generating IDs until you get one that *does* have a hash ending in a 1. But as I say, it's a horrible idea - it's possible but *not* what you should be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As lots of other people here have pointed out, the root cause is the database design, which you should change. If, for whatever reason, you can't do that, then you could consider obscuring the prefix a bit.

One option would be to say that all characters `a-m` represent `g`, and all the other other characters `n-z` represent `b`. This would mean that you could randomly decide to encode the ID `g1234` as `a1234`, `h1234`, or `l1234`, but when you have to decode it, you'd know that they'd all three mean `g1234`.

Another rule could be to say that all vowels `a,e,i,o,u,y` represent `g`, and all consonants represent `b`. Again, this'd enable you to decode `i1234` as `g1234`, but `h1234` as `b1234`.

For really astute users of the site, this might still be detectable, but IME, most users don't even look at the address bar in order to see if their connection is secure or not...

Even so, you could invent your own algorithm. You only need it to be deterministic when you decode it.

But you should really change the database design.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem stems from an incorrect database design. You can go all out and try to work around this choice, but the more sensible approach would be to revise that design.

Don't store entities in different tables just because they differ by a single attribute. What's next, a `grMobiles` for good red mobiles, and `bbMobiles` for bad black mobiles? And why prepend the prefix to the primary key anyway? It's already in the table name.

The solution is to save the "quality" attribute in a separate column in the same table. This will solve all your problems, and in the future even allow you to sell "mediocre" mobiles apart from good and bad ones.

Comment: Exactly! next round would be grsMobiles vs bblMobiles. care to guess what the s and l stands for? :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled short & long ?

Comment: @Rafalon almost... I was thinking small and large.

Comment: @ZoharPeled close enough ^^

Comment: @ZoharPeled would be more fun if it was bad black compact mobile, don't you think? :D

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you should change the design of your table(s) so you have only one table with an additional column.

If you can't change this, another solution could be to pass the id in a **POST** request instead of a **GET** request, so it will **not be displayed in the URL**.

People could still figure out if your mobiles are good or bad, but it won't be **obvious** to most users.